# A problem exists with the security proof in the secure AND example in the malicious model

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis, security-definition

Imagine that the malicious adversary in the real world uses $Y = 0$ as its input, therefore he computes the output as ($X$ && $y=0$) = $0$. We can conclude that the real view in the real world is as:

Real view: $X, Y = 0$ and $output = 0$

**Real World**

[image: Real model]

Now, imagine the simulator wants to simulate the real world’s view in the ideal world. In order to simulate $x$ (honest party’s input), the simulator must send $1$ to the trusted party and then receives $x$ from it. Thus the simulator succeeded to simulate $X$, but now the simulator computes the output as
 $X$ && $(Y = 1)$ = $X$, which is not the equal of the output in the real view $X$ && $0$ = $0$. Thus the simulator cannot simulate the output in the ideal model.

**Ideal World**

[image: Ideal World]

**Definition 2.3.1 in the malicious model**

[image: Definition 2.3.1]

The definition says that for every adversary A for the real model must exist a simulator S for the ideal model. Considering this definition, I could find an adversary (who sends $y = 0$ in the real world) that there is no any simulator for it, so the protocol is not secure in the malicious model. In the Lindell’s book-page 27 (the below proof), it is said that this protocol is secure!!! I am so confused. (I found a scenario where the protocol is not secure).

**Proof of the protocol**

[image: Proof of the protocol]

Comment: You ask quite a few questions in different directions which will likely fend people off from answering because during the time it takes to write a proper answer you could ask more questions, *ad infinitum*. Please focus here, to get answers.

Comment: Additionally to what @fkraiem said (which I re-formulated a bit to sound nicer) remember that it is no problem to split your question up into multiple distinct questions.

Comment: @SEJPM This reads like "I've detected a problem and here's my blog post". Especially, since I have a hard time identifying a question (not only due to the lack of even a single question mark). Therefore, I'm putting this on-hold for OP to clarify with an edit.

Comment: @SEJPM I got my answer. fkraiem answered my question, and I have no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you consider an adversary $\mathcal A$ corrupting $P_2$ in the real world, and which ignores $P_2$'s input $y$ and just outputs $0$ regardless of the value $x$ sent by $P_1$, is that right? And you claim that this adversary is not simulatable.

Well, of course this adversary is simulatable: the simulator sends whatever to the trusted party, receives whatever, and outputs $0$.

The proof, by the way, shows more: it shows how to construct a simulator for any adversary, as follows. In the real world, the adversary receives $x$, performs whatever computation based on $x$, $y$, and its auxiliary output $z$, and outputs the result. The simulator sends $1$ to the trusted party, receives $x$, performs the same computation as the real-world adversary, and outputs its result.

Comment: The adversary A uses Y = 0 as its input in the real world, then computes output as (X && (Y=0)) =0.
Now, my question is: 
When the simulator gets X from the trusted party, it computes output as (X && Y = 1) = X. As you can see the output in the ideal world(X) is not the same as the output in the real world(0).

Comment: @AmirHoseinAdavoudi A malicious adversary is not required to perform the operations prescribed by the protocol, and can do whatever it wants. That's the whole point! We want to show that even such an adversary cannot breach the privacy of computation.

Comment: Suppose that the adversary $A$ ignore the corrupted P2's input and uses $Y=0$ as its input, so the output in the real model will be $X$ && $Y=0$) = $0$, but the simulator computes output as $X$ && $Y=1$ = $X$.
Because the simulator used $Y=1$ for obtaining $X$, it will compute output as ($X$ && ($Y=1$))=$X$.

Thus the output in the real model,$0$, is not equal to the output in the ideal model, $X$.

Comment: @AmirHoseinAdavoudi *Your* simulator doesn't work, but mine does, so there is a simulator that works. :)

Comment: Just one more question, would you please tell me in the example how the simulator computes output? Please give me the formula that it computes.
What is the value of the $Y$?

Comment: @AmirHoseinAdavoudi My simulator does not compute anything; it just outputs $0$, like your real-world adversary does.

Comment: In the real model, P2 has an output which is (X && Y), so I think that the simulator must compute the output like the real model.

Comment: @AmirHoseinAdavoudi Where in the definition of security in the malicious model does it say anything about how the simulator must compute its output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82543/discussion-between-fkraiem-and-amirhosein-adavoudi).